# Can I run self hosted(Owin based) Web Api on Android using Xamarin or any other alternative framework

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin, asp.net-web-api2, .net-core

I would like to run self hosted Asp.Net Web API on Andorid or Windows mobile.
Can I use use Xamarin for this? Since .Net Core is open source and cross platform, I believe it is theoretically possible. But not sure about this. Suggestions for any other cross platform mobile frameworks are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use asp.net web API on Android, I am using the same technique. Answering further, I was working on Android Studio previously, now I am using Xamarin and I have used the same API for both. Let me know if you want any help. you can also use the APIs from the localhost if the devices are in the same network

> Happy Coding

Comment: This looks great. Can you share further details of the code or share the sample code here or on github.

Comment: Hello @parag glad that the answer was helpful. I think you'll get the guides to use asp.net web API somewhere, not a hard task I guess.let me know if you've some problem executing.

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni mb i am to stupid to google. but can u provide a resource on how to do that? thank you

Comment: I get the following error "Could not install package 'Owin 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1'"